# I Hope You Like Connect Walls! #2

Tags: word, connect-wall

Like last time, find the links then connect it to a Puzzling SE tag.

> ```
>        ununoctium        tone         puking        tinned
>
>          romans       snapdragon      canine        hijack
>
>         shoebill        stomach      asterisk    minimalistic  
>
>         incubate       listener     freighter      duchesses
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible partition gives the first set:

> t**one**, ca**nine**, lis**ten**er, fr**eight**er → hidden numerals

Second set:

> r**oman**s, p**uk**ing, mini**mali**stic, in**cuba**te → hidden countries

Third set:

> tin**ned**, hi**jack**, shoe**bill**, s**tom**ach → hidden male first names

Fourth set:

> un**uno**ctium,  **snap**dra**go**n,  aste**risk**, du**chess**es
>  Uno is a card game, snap (cards) or go, risk and chess are games

Perhaps the tag is

> [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) as hidden words may be a feature of this tag.

Comment: Hmm... Rot13(Znyv) again, @aguy? (Presuming this answer is correct.) :P

Comment: being a bit fussy maybe, but isn't [nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) a game too?

Comment: and [ali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali) as a male name

Comment: Correct remarks, but don't see a way to fit into 4 groups. The tag I gave is a bit general.

Comment: This is correct, and sorry about the tag being too general, but I thought there was a hidden-words tag when posting. There isn't. And user477343, sorry for putting Mali in two connect-walls.