# Connect Wall Puzzle

Tags: word, wordplay, connect-wall

This is my first try on Connect Walls, please tell me what I can improve on. Thanks!

Inspired by [I Hope You Like Connect Walls! #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/76196/i-hope-you-like-connect-walls-2)

**INSTRUCTIONS:**

1. Find the hidden word in each word
2. Group them into groups
3. Find the tag on Puzzling SE I am referring to

**THE WORDS**

Adonai, asphyxiant, climate, crust,

delocalise, energization, gesturally, glottogony,

machinate, petnapper, plenary, prolonged,

schadenfreude, shredding, sloganise, stoneboat

**NOTE**

I am sorry that one of the words can fit into two groups. Please place it in the best group according to your general knowledge and common sense. It should be sufficient enough.

Comment: Do not add irrelevant text to the question; I've rolled back the irrelevant "promotion". (Also, you should know that words fitting into multiple groups is a feature, not a bug! In the original show that these puzzles are based off of, several words can fit into two or even three groups -- but you can use the knowledge of all four groups to disambiguate.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the tag you are referring to is

> geography

Countries

> cr**US**t, ma**CHINA**te, glot**TOGO**ny, s**CHAD**enfreude,

Mountains

> p**ETNA**pper, s**LOGAN**ise, gest**URAL**ly, sto**NEBO**at

Regional Capital cities

> asphy**XI'AN**t, c**LIMA**te, delo**CALI**se, ener**GIZA**tion

Rivers

> a**DON**ai, ple**NAR**y, pro**LONG**ed, sh**RED**ding

Comment: All correct! +1 plus the tick!